# rpm install package with obsolete error

Tags: rpm, obsolete

I hit one problem during install some dependency packages.

I have two yum repo, repo1 and repo2 both provide one dependency
For example, one is **python-XXXXX**, the other is **python2-XXXXX**
They have different version info

python-XXXXX was built by own and it is `1.5.0`. And the other one is default repo own and it is `2.6.0`

When install upstream package, it will install this dependency.

> Upstream require < 1.6.0

So I assume it will try to find lower version one.

But during installation, I found seemed it try to install higher version one.

> [...]
>   Package python-oslo-i18n is obsoleted by python2-oslo-i18n, but obsoleting package does not provide for requirements
>   --> Finished Dependency Resolution
>
> Error: Package: python-oslo-messaging-1.8.3-1.noarch (repo1)
>
> Requires: python-oslo-i18n < 1.6.0
>
> Available: python-oslo-i18n-1.5.0-2.noarch (repo1)
>              python-oslo-i18n = 1.5.0-2
>
> Installing: python2-oslo-i18n-2.6.0-1.el7_1.1.noarch (repo2)
>               python-oslo-i18n = 2.6.0-1.el7_1.1

I guess keyword Obsolete has been defined in **python2-XXXXX** so during installation, it will try to remove correct one.
But I did not understand why it can not find correct one

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?
I can work around by disable repo which contain higher version one.

But I still need that repo later.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yum supports the exclusion of individual packages from a repository.  In the yum configuration of the system where you are doing the updates, try adding this:

```
exclude=python*
```

add it to the configuration section of 'repo2' (perhaps in /etc/yum.repos.d/repo2)